# parameter to the java compiler of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, compiler-optimization

I am not able to find how to add/edit parameter to the java compiler of Eclipse. 
for eg. -parameter 
I am using ECLIPSE LUNA and no means of setting options in Java Compiler Properties.

Comment: Run > Run Configurations

Comment: Eclipse uses its own Java compiler which does not use the same options as javac

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried on "Run Configurations"?

Run -> Run Configurations... -> Arguments tab, set there your Program and/or VM arguments.

Comment: That sets the options for running the Java program, it does not set the Java Compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

All options understood by Eclipse's compiler for Java are indeed configurable by the [Java Compiler Preferences / Properties](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fref-preferences-compiler.htm&cp=25_4_2_0_3)

If there's any option your missing on this page and its sub pages, please be specific.